# How to change the fontFamily on the overflow menu listview text

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the overflow menu listview text for my app, but I'm not having any luck. I can change the textColor and textSize, but not the fontFamily.

Here is my styles:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/PopupMenuTextView</item>
    <!-- this takes care of the bottom divider -->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>

<!--Change Overflow Menu ListView Text Size and Text Size -->
<style name="PopupMenuTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item> <!-- works -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-thin</item> <!-- doesn't work!!!!!! -->
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item> <!-- works -->
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the parent declaration in the PopMenuTextView style and check if in that case the font is applied?

Comment: Just tried it. Same results. :(

Comment: It's a pity, maybe you have to set the Typeface in execution time, as if you were applying any other custom font in a regular TextView.